# Why I can not disable module using system config advanced?

Tags: magento

I am facing this for a long time now. I am not able to disable module using config->Advanced(Not disabling the output).
After selecting to disable it and save it, output still shows up.

Every time I have to jump into the code to disable it.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: The settings in 'Advanced >> Advanced' do not disable the module, only module output. To disable a module completely, you have to disable it in /app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml

Comment: The module it self might not be configured properly the system->advanced functionality is not intended to add and remove modules..

Comment: Sorry I meant to say not disabling the output. I have edited it now

Comment: Is this a stock Magento Module, a module you bought or a module you programmed up yourself? The answers have all been off the mark as this important piece of information was not in the original question.

Comment: It's a very simple module I have created by myself

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this in your xml file at location `/app/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentocustmod_HideEmptyCategories>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentocustmod_HideEmptyCategories>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now change  `<active>true</active>` to  `<active>false</active>` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to flush your cache in order for the modules **output** to be disabled.

Please note: all the backend does is disable the **output** and not the module itself.

To disable the module itself, you need to go to the modules XML file in app/etc/modules and turn the active tag to 'false'

Comment: Sorry It doesn't even disable the output, even after flushing cache.

Comment: You didn't fully read his answer. Read the last sentence, paragraph 3, follow it and then clear the cache. Also answered here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34244/temporarily-disable-magento-extensions-from-the-back-end/34644#34644

Comment: I read it. I want to disable the output from the admin config advanced. Please read my question. app/etc/modules is working fine.

Comment: Well, in that case, has the module been written to read the configuration and disable its output when setting it disabled in System Config/Advanced?

Comment: isn't it obvious if it is showing in Advanced? or is there any other setting?

Comment: The setting is just a setting, the code has to read it and do something with it. I assumed since Stack Overflow is a programming question site, that this module is something you created. We need further information as we obviously are guessing due to not knowing what the module actually is.