# How to disable custom module in magento

Tags: magento, module

I have overridden core file in my custom module extension.

Disabling this module using magento admin panel is not working.

```
system -> configuration -> Advanced
Module Name (drop down option - disable)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting. Not working can mean anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I can not disable module using system config advanced?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130784/why-i-can-not-disable-module-using-system-config-advanced)

Comment: He means disabling it isn't working ... he's right of course disabling only disables the output.

Answer (score 5):

When we disable module from admin, it only disables html output on frontend.

Module config file still loads when module is disable from admin, so your override functionality is still loaded with this module, so try to disable that module from config file.

Try `<active>false</active>` in your module etc `.xml` file.

Comment: Are there any caches to refresh, scripts to run? What I see is that the module is still active despite the XML file (in my case it's an _all.xml with many module defs at once) the module is set to false.

Comment: Yes you need to refresh cache from backend if cache is enable

Comment: I have the cache disabled in the backend already. Still it's not getting deactivated.

Comment: @hakre Can you share your xml code or ask as new question

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to disable the module via terminal

`bin/magento module:disable ${MODULE_NAME}`

If it says there is no such module, try listing all enabled ones to find yours

`bin/magento module:status --enabled`

Reference to [official dosc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html)